# How to draw a face using a method

Tags: java, function, methods, graphics

I am drawing the face from the drawFace funtion 1 time.  I want to call that function in the paint method so it will draw the face multiple times at x/y co-ordinates i specify.

```
public class smilingfacefunction extends Canvas
{
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    drawFace(g, 500, 300);
    drawFace(g, 100, 100);
}

public void drawFace (Graphics g, int x, int y)
{

g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
g.fillOval(100, 100, 100, 100);
g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
g.fillOval(125, 125, 20, 20);
g.fillOval(155, 125, 20, 20);
g.setColor(Color.red);
g.drawArc(125,150,40,40,0,-180);
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
   JFrame win = new JFrame("Smile");
   win.setSize(700, 700);
   win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   win.add(new smilingfacefunction());
   win.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Comment: Your `drawFace` function has to make its draws on the `x` and `y` parameter. You are not using them

Comment: @Isac how do i use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `drawFace` method has to use the `x` and `y` parameter as a reference point from where to start drawing. Something like this:

```
public void drawFace (Graphics g, int x, int y)
{
   g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
   g.fillOval(x, y, 100, 100);
   g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
   g.fillOval(x + 25, y + 25, 20, 20);
   g.fillOval(x + 55, y + 25, 20, 20);
   g.setColor(Color.red);
   g.drawArc(x + 25, y + 50, 40, 40, 0, -180);
}
```

You can now fine tune the drawing so that the elements are placed where you want them for each face.

Comment: Thanks alot massive help.